# URL was already generated for an item with SKU. ERROR

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, url-key

I have problem when trying to import products via CSV i get this error:

1. Url key: '******' was already generated for an item with the SKU:'*******'. You need to specify the unique URL key manually en filas: 2, 3, 5

the problem is that i have 170 rows of this, is there any chance that when magento recognize this error add "-(number)" after to product url key?

Comment: I make a feature request in FireGento_ExtendedImport2 https://github.com/firegento/FireGento_ExtendedImport2/issues/21

Answer (score 4):

This is strange bug in Magento.

This will happened - if URL-key exist in Magento,
and if Product name exist in Magento.

If each Products will with Unique Name - will be all OK.
Becouse URL-key based in Product name.

This very strange logic by Magento.

So,
for fix this bug need to edit file
vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php

1. change isNeedToValidateUrlKey

   ```
     private function isNeedToValidateUrlKey($rowData)
     {
        return (!empty($rowData[self::URL_KEY]))
             && (empty($rowData[self::COL_VISIBILITY])
             || $rowData[self::COL_VISIBILITY]
             !== (string)Visibility::getOptionArray()[Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE]);
     }
   ```
2. change getUrlKey

   ```
   protected function getUrlKey($rowData)
    {
     if (!empty($rowData[self::URL_KEY])) {
         return strtolower($rowData[self::URL_KEY]);
     }

     if (!empty($rowData[self::COL_NAME])) {
        return $this->productUrl->formatUrlKey($rowData[self::COL_NAME].'-'.$rowData[self::COL_SKU]);
     }

     return '';
   }
   ```
3. change _saveProducts -
   cut code - $rowData[self::URL_KEY] = $this->getUrlKey($rowData);
   and insert under - $rowSku = $rowData[self::COL_SKU];
   following code

   ```
   if ($this->isSkuExist($rowSku)) {
    if (!empty($rowData[self::URL_KEY])) {
        $rowData[self::URL_KEY] = $this->getUrlKey($rowData);
    } else {

    }
     } else {
    $rowData[self::URL_KEY] = $this->getUrlKey($rowData);
   }
   ```

Now if in import CSV file - not exist column url_key,
will set url_key like **ProductName-ProductSku**

And without bugs :)

Comment: Great finding :)

Comment: great, but is it a good idea to modify the core files?

Comment: Ofcourse you can add changes with plugins. 
But can take additional time.. a lot of time.
 

Also better use latest Magento version, maybe some bugs are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. You need to check the names of your products.

You also can check at this closed issue at Magento's github repository.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1471

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate url issue can be fixed by install this extension https://github.com/ho-nl/magento2-Ho_Import

It'll add a postfix -1, -2 in your url generated